# Using pipenv behind a proxy

Tags: python, pipenv

How do I use pipenv behind a proxy?

An old thread in github says no (https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/987) I don't find something in the documentation (https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 6):

In your user folder create a pip folder, if not already present, 
and create a pip.ini file in it containing

```
  [global]
  trusted-host = pypi.python.org
                 pypi.org
                 files.pythonhosted.org
  proxy = <proxy:port>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Seems to help, but it's not enough. pipenv is using urllib directly, for which setting environment variables (`http_proxy` and `https_proxy`) is needed.

Comment: @TTimo Thanks for this. Your comment works for me. In my case, setting both environment variables worked.