# pipenv install failing behind proxy

Tags: python, pip, proxy, pipenv

There is a Pipfile and a Pipfile.lock. I am new to the code and want to create a virtual environment based on the Pipfile.lock

I have installed pipenv (v2022.7.4).
I am running python 3.8.13 using visual studio code and created a virtual environment through the Anaconda navigator.
It's a virtual desktop running Windows server 2012R2, I know, but I cannot upgrade this.

I can pip install packages providing I specify the trusted and proxy (no password required here):

```
pip install --user --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --proxy='http://name_of_my_proxy:1234' package_name_here
```

However, when running "pipenv install", it errors.
I have followed the suggestions on stack overflow
[Using pipenv behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817886/using-pipenv-behind-a-proxy) and manually created a pip.ini file. The pip.ini file is being found because running "pip config list", lists the variables I added to the pip.ini file:

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org
proxy = http://name_of_my_proxy:1234
```

I have tried adding these as well to the pip.ini file:

```
http_proxy = http://name_of_my_proxy:1234
https_proxy = https://name_of_my_proxy:1234
```

It looks like for every package the same error occurs, this is the error for the first package:

```
'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /packages/e0/e9/359dbb77c35c419df0aedeb1d53e71e7e3f438ff64a8fdb048c907404de3/alembic-1.4.1.tar.gz
```

I'm not sure what to try next.
Pretty sure that this isn't relevant [How to configure PIP per config file to use a proxy (with authentification)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473041/how-to-configure-pip-per-config-file-to-use-a-proxy-with-authentification)

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that there is plain HTTP going to HTTPS port or either way around.